# Open only taking one positional argument in python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, arguments, raspberry-pi3

I'm having trouble with the [Open() function](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) in python. It's only taking one positional argument in some cases, and other times it's fine.

In one file, this works perfectly, but in another, an error code pops up saying open only takes one argument.

`w = open("file.txt", "w")`

`TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

The file that works is on my windows machine, but it doesn't work every time. It doesn't seem to work at all on my Raspberry Pi.

Is this an issue with my interpreter? If so, can anyone suggest what I can do, or if there's another way to read and write to text files?

Comment: can you be more specific, what do you mean doesn't work, what error code

Comment: It can only mean that in the problematic script, `open` refers to something different than that of standard library. There should be somewhere in that script that says `open = ...`, or maybe a `from module import *` that messes the global namespace.

Comment: @AlexisDrakopoulos The error code I get is "TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Comment: @Rightleg I've found about importing os, and using open completely differently, and it seems to work. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's better explained in the python docs. You can access the info on open function through the link

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Thank you for this! I had a look at it and it explained open.os, which does work for me. I'm still getting used to the syntax around it, but it works!